# New MVC 5 App template doesn't run

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015

I am new to VS 2015 and MVC5, but I've used MVC3. I just created a new project using the first few steps in this tutorial (web app):

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on

When I try to run the app, it times out every time when I access the localhost address. I'm running behind a proxy, but I have my internet options set to ignore the proxy for localhost. I haven't changed a thing from the template. I am wondering if anyone may know what is going on? Any troubleshooting suggestions?

Thanks for any help,

-Jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-created the project and it worked the second time.